# How to change a hard coded String Array to a String[] myString = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.myStringArray);

Tags: java, android, arrays, eclipse, string

I am quite new to this android eclipse programing. i have spent days searching the web for an answer but have not been able to find one yet.
i have managed to get a listview working using fragments but the string data is hard coded and i would like to use a string from the resources xml file.

this is the hard coded data

```
public static final String[] message1 = new String[] { "Strawberry",
       "Banana", "Orange", "Mixed" };
```

this is my string 
//String array data to display for row data message1

```
String[] message1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_page_list_string);
```

from my strings.xml file

```
<string-array name="main_page_list_string">
    <item >Instruments</item>
    <item >Capasiters</item>
    <item >Resisters</item>
    <item >Ohms Law</item>
    <item >IP Ratings</item>
    <item>Thermostats</item>
    <item>Converters</item>
    <item >RJ 45 A and B plugs</item><item>Calculators</item>
</string-array>
```

every time i replace

```
public static final String[] message1 = new String[] { "Strawberry",
       "Banana", "Orange", "Mixed" };
```

with

```
String[] message1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_page_list_string);
```

my app crashes and the error message is null point exception.

can anyone tell me how to do this?`enter code here`
thanks

This is the  java class file

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ImageTextListBaseAdapterActivity extends Activity implements
OnItemClickListener {

  ***********************************************************************************
  This is the code i am trying to use
    //String array data to display for row data message1
    String[] myStringData=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_page_list_string); 

    This is the code that i am trying to replace 

   ********************************************************************************  
    //    public static final String[] message1 = new String[] { "Strawberry",
    //        "Banana", "Orange", "Mixed" };
   ******************************************************************************
    //String array data to display for row data message2
    public static final String[] descriptions = new String[] {
        "It is an aggregate accessory fruit",
        "It is the largest herbaceous flowering plant", "Citrus Fruit",
    "Mixed Fruits" };

    //icons used in list item rows
    public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.ic_launcher,
        R.drawable.songs_gray, R.drawable.videos_gray, R.drawable.photos_gray };

    ListView listView;
    List<RowItem> rowItems;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fragment_mainlist);

        rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
        for (int i = 0; i < message1.length; i++) {
            RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], message1[i], descriptions[i]);
            rowItems.add(item);
        }

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.MainPageListView);
        CustomBaseAdapter adapter = new CustomBaseAdapter(this, rowItems);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Item " + (position + 1) + ": " + rowItems.get(position),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

this is the error from LogCat

07-22 08:41:12.659: E/AndroidRuntime(13799): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-22 08:41:12.659: E/AndroidRuntime(13799): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.rogerssteve.android.elecinstro/com.rogerssteve.android.elecinstro.ImageTextListBaseAdapterActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-22 08:41:12.659: E/AndroidRuntime(13799):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)

i cannot see any line numbers?

Comment: Suggest you post your `getResources()` and `getStringArray()` functions so we can see what you're trying to do. I would think at first glance, you might want to look in to some sort of XML parser such as that offered by JAXB to get data from your XML file.

Comment: @RyanJ those functions are part of is Android API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you are changing a constant `static final` which is accessible without object instance to a field which requite an instance  first off all i would recommend moving your initalisation to constructor of your object

```
public class Sample {

    String[] message1 ;

    public Sample(){
         message1 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.main_page_list_string);
    }
}
```

To tell you a bit more you need to paste your error message (edit : sorry to more specific what i mean is an error message gives you an exact line where was NPE,  could you paste exact line ?)

Comment: hi all well i found the answer, this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12506045/how-to-use-getstring-on-static-string-before-oncreate
explanations the problem and the answer was easy after that
thanks all